# Segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes - Java

Tags: java, algorithm

So I was trying to implement Segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes in Java and this is the best I could do. When I run it, it gives no errors but it doesn't return anything, despite me added "System.out.println" at the end to print out all the remaining primes. Thanks in advance for the recommendations

```
public class SegmentedSieveofEratosthenes  {

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = in.nextInt();
    int m = in.nextInt();
    boolean[] v = new boolean[1000000];
    int[] primes = new int[1000000];
    //counter for the primes vector
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i=2;i<=(int)Math.sqrt(m);i++)
    {
        v[i]=true;
    }

    for(int i=2;i<=(int)Math.sqrt(m);i++)
    {
        if(v[i]=true)
        {
            primes[counter]=i;
            counter=counter+1;
            for(int j=i+1;j<=(int)Math.sqrt(m);j++)
            {
                if(j%i==0)
                {
                    v[j]=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    boolean[] flags = new boolean[1000000];
    for(int i=n;i<=m;i++)
    {
        flags[i]=true;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
        int start = (n/primes[i])*3;
        for(int j=start+i;j<=m;j=j+i)
            flags[j]=false;
    }

    for(int i=n;i<=m;i++)
        if(flags[i]==true)
            System.out.println(i);

    in.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just a comment: choose a curly brace style. The communities of same line curly and next line curly don't get along. This style of using both will create a war the likes of which you have never seen.

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz Oh ok, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were three distinct problems with your implementation. The first issue was that you were assigning `v[i]` to true in a condition

```
if(v[i]=true)
```

Then there were a few off-by-one errors in the termination condition of the for loops, specifically

```
for (...; i<=m; ...)
```

instead of

```
for (...; i<m; ...)
```

And then lastly, something was off in your math for the the following

```
int start = (n/primes[i])*3;
for(int j=start+i;j<=m;j=j+i)
    flags[j]=false;
```

I'm sure it was a small fix, but I couldn't figure it out so I just wrote my own

```
int start = n + (-n % primes[i]);
for(int j=start;j<m;j+=primes[i])
    flags[j]=false;
```

Additionally, I made a few small changes to your sieve to speed things up. Rather than checking every number following a prime modulo said prime, I start at `prime^2` (where `^` denotes exponentiation) and increment by `prime`, only flagging multiples with no wasted checks.

Original

```
primes[counter]=i;
counter=counter+1;
for(int j=i+1;j<=(int)Math.sqrt(m);j++)
{
    if(j%i==0)
    {
        v[j]=false;
    }
}
```

Optimized

```
primes[counter++]=i;
for(int j=i*i;j<=(int)Math.sqrt(m);j+=i)
{
    v[j]=false;
}
```

Put together-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class SegmentedSieveofEratosthenes  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        boolean[] v = new boolean[1000000];
        int[] primes = new int[1000000];
        //counter for the primes vector
        int counter = 0;

        for(int i=2;i<=(int)Math.sqrt(m);i++)
        {
            v[i]=true;
        }

        for(int i=2;i<=(int)Math.sqrt(m);i++)
        {
            if(v[i])
            {
                primes[counter++]=i;
                for(int j=i*i;j<=(int)Math.sqrt(m);j+=i)
                {
                    v[j]=false;
                }
            }
        }

        boolean[] flags = new boolean[1000000];
        for(int i=n;i<m;i++)
        {
            flags[i]=true;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
        {
            int start = n + (-n % primes[i]);
            for(int j=start;j<m;j+=primes[i])
                if (j != primes[i])
                    flags[j]=false;
        }

        for(int i=n;i<m;i++)
            if(flags[i])
                System.out.println(i);

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Output for `n = 800` and `m == 1000` for example

```
809
811
821
823
827
829
839
853
857
859
863
877
881
883
887
907
911
919
929
937
941
947
953
967
971
977
983
991
997
```

Comment: Hi Dillion! Thank you so much for your response. I implemented it in my code and now it works great! But, between the two ranges of numbers I put, it does not include the "m" or the last one into account. That's why I kept adding for (...; I <=m; ...) because I wanted the program to check whether or not even m is prime or not. What do you suggest me to do now? Will it be better if I just do the last case outside the for loop and on its own? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend `int m = in.nextInt() + 1;`, which will then include `m`.

Comment: @TheSilentCoder.   Also, I want to mention (but did not put in the post, because you did not mention performance) that this can be optimized even faster quite easily by replacing all occurrences of `(int)Math.sqrt(m)` with a variable you compute once at the beginning. Additionally, if you hard code in the prime `2`, all others will be odd, so you can increment by 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Also, if this answers your question, feel free to accept it so that others can see the problem has been solved.

Comment: @Dillion Davis, Thank you so much for the help and I checked your answer! But, try your solution with 2 and 10, I believe it doesn't work. Is there any way this can be changed? Here is my code right now: [link]( https://codeshare.io/alx4em) Thanks again!

Comment: You can modify the code because I believe it's a real time editor

Comment: @TheSilentCoder updated-  the issue was that it didn't consider that for `n < sqrt(m)`, any "multiples" of `prime[i]` may actually be `prime[i]` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have never ending cycle in the following line:

```
for(int j=start+i;j<=m;j=j+i)
```

as variables **i**, **j** and **start** always equal 0.

Learn to debug your programs, it will help you a lot ;)

p.s. keep your code clean, use spaces in expressions like **i = n; i < m;** instead of i=n;i

Comment: There were more problems than just that line-  see my answer.  But I do want to say I absolutely agree with your note on formatting. In my answer I preserved OP's formatting for consistency, but I would never write a condition like that outside of code golf in practice.