# Print first 100000 Prime numbers in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I was trying to build a simple program in Java to print the first N prime numbers.

Here is my program, it's working fine up to input N=10000, but if we increase the input to N=100000, it goes into a continuous loop and takes a lot of time. I tried to optimize it more so that it can work fine for the input N=100000, but no luck far. Could you please suggest if we can optimize the code so that it will work fine for the larger inputs?

```
public class PrintPrimes {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);  //it will take input
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int number = 3;
    System.out.print("2" + " ");
    while (n > 1) {
        if (checkPrime(number)) {
            System.out.print(number + " ");
            n--;
        }
        number++;
    }
  }

public static boolean checkPrime(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Your help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You could implement a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_and_variants).

Comment: The method that you are implementing here is the notorious [Trial Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division).  I say notorious because programmers often mistakenly think that it is the Sieve of Eratosthenes, or effectively the same as it.  However the real Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm has no divisions and also has a much smaller Big-O complexity and thus runs much faster.

Comment: Your int overflows silently.  Switch to long.

Comment: [one more option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366942/prime-number-in-java-8/44376332#44376332)

Comment: For N=100000 it runs in about 2 minutes on my notebook. However, i replaced `.print` with `.println` - i suspect accumulating 100000 results in a single line uses a lot memory and CPU for buffering.

Comment: Hi everyone, Thank you so much for the help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066310/segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes-java resolved my query, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

```java
int n = s.nextInt();
boolean[] prime = new boolean[n + 1];
Arrays.fill(prime, true);
for(int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++){
    if(prime[i]){
        for(int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i){
            prime[j] = false;
        }
    }
}
for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
    if(prime[i]) System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing, Sieve of Eratosthenes resolved my query. But, I think the above program is not giving the expected results. By the way thanks for the help.

Comment: @PrashantBalotra What output is it giving that is not expected?

Comment: Hi @Unmitigated, actually it is working fine, but I was expecting that it will print the first 100000 prime numbers if we input 100000, but as per checking I guess this is print prime numbers up to 100000 (i.e. prime numbers which are less than 100000). But that's also great. I will do the remaining part and already accepted the solution, Thanks!